# No resource identifier found for attribute 'cardElevation' in package 'com.facebook.samples.audiencenetwork'

Tags: android, facebook, xamarin

I have tried to use Xamarin Android Facebook Component to native login to Facebook. but I get these two errorrs:

No resource identifier found for attribute 'cardElevation' in package 'com.facebook.samples.audiencenetwork'

No resource identifier found for attribute 'cardBackgroundColor' in package 'com.facebook.samples.audiencenetwork'

Would you please tell me how to solve it?

Answer (score 2):

I found the problem.

1- do not install the SDK as a component
2- Add these DLLs: Xamarin .Support .v4 
                   Xamarin .Support.v7 .CardView
                   Xamarin .Support .v7 .AppCompat
                   Xamarin .Facebook

And it will work

Comment: could you post the actual versions of these dlls?